# 1.7MHz Square wave generator

Tags: arduino-uno

```
const uint8_t OUTPUT_PIN = 3;  // = OC2B
const uint8_t PERIOD = 9;      // 9 CPU cycles ~ 1.778 MHz

void setup()
{
    pinMode(OUTPUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
    TCCR2B = 0;           // stop timer
    TCNT2  = 0;           // reset timer
    TCCR2A = _BV(COM2B1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC2B
           | _BV(WGM20)   // fast PWM mode, TOP = OCR2A
           | _BV(WGM21);  // ...ditto
    TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22);  // ...ditto
    OCR2A = PERIOD - 1;
    OCR2B = PERIOD/2 - 1;
}

void soundBuzzer() {
    TCCR2B |= _BV(CS20);  // F_CPU / 1
}

void silenceBuzzer() {
    TCCR2B &= ~_BV(CS20);
    TCNT2 = 0;
}
```

[I got it from here, look down to the answers](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37613/generate-1-7-mhz-with-pwm-in-uno)

This program supposed to generate a square-wave of frequency around 1.7MHz but it is not working for me. I have tried the simulation on Proteus 8 and there is no output. Only one error shows during the compilation which is the 'loop' function is missing, I have added one and still there is no output. Please somebody help me.

Comment: i suggest that you start by exporing the example sketches in the Arduino IDE ... pay attention to the format of the sketches

Answer (score 1):

In the `setup` there is some settings for timer2, but no change of prescaller, so the timer stays stopped.

Obviously it was started by calling `soundBuzzer()` somewhere in code. But this function name is now kinda misleading. Just set prescaller in the `setup` and it should be working.